# Asian ecological movie with three superpowered women and a corrupt government limiting access to water

Tags: story-identification, movie, powers

I have been looking for this movie for a while now (it is an old movie).  The movie is either Chinese or Japanese, set in a modern society, and deals with three superhero women; I think they are sisters.

One sister has recently married and had a baby; her husband is in a position of power, either a police officer or in the government.  The women can fly, use weapons well, and have super-strength.

The corrupt government is trying to control the people by limiting water to only a select few to make slaves of the people; they have hidden the reservoirs and the sisters go looking for the water.

Comment: By "old", how old? Animated or live-action?

Comment: possibly related to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/235435/film-about-three-women-fighting-a-skeletal-creature

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure you are remembering ***[Executioners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executioners_(film))***, a Hong Kong film from the 1990s, directed by   Johnny To and Ching Siu-tung. The three heroines are played by **Michelle Yeoh, Anita Mui** and **Maggie Cheung,** in a sequel to a film in which they were also co-stars: ***[The Heroic Trio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Heroic_Trio)***.

[image: movie still, character with a sword]

Here's a quote from a bare-bones plot summary that's attached to [the IMDb listing](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108606/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl) for the film. It's close enough to your summary-from-memory to strongly suggest that this is the same film you were recalling.

> Set some time after the original 'Heroic Trio,' the city has been
>   devastated by nuclear attack. An evil deformed villain controls the
>   city's scarce water supply, exerting influence over both a popular
>   leader and a militarist colonel. The trio of Chat the Thief Catcher,
>   Ching, and Wonder Woman (along with her young daughter) have to avert a
>   military takeover and find clean headwaters to save the city.

(Note: The reference to "Wonder Woman" does not mean that the producers had permission to use the DC Comics superhero character known as "Wonder Woman." I'm guessing that this is just a close translation of whatever the original Chinese phrase was that was used for Anita Mui's character, who did **not** come across as being a princess from a secret island inhabited by the Amazon women-warriors of Greek Myth.)