# Film about three women fighting a skeletal creature

Tags: story-identification, movie

I watched this film about 2000-2005.

This is a Hong Kong film. I only remember the last scene, a fight where three girls fight with a skeletal creature. He gets a bone plug in the flesh of one of the women and controls her actions. She attacks the other two and takes some hits. In the end, all three are alive.

What I remember but am not sure of: 1 of the 3 females was originally a member of the organization of which the "skeleton-like creature" is the boss. She loves a scientist who is captured then she turns to the good side. Then she tricks her boss and bombs him, maybe revealing his true nature?

I am sure this is not a horror film.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the 1993 film, [*The Heroic Trio*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Heroic_Trio).

> An invisible woman is kidnapping newborn babies who are destined to be emperors and delivering them to the mysterious subterranean supernatural Evil Master. The police are powerless, and the city must be saved by three very different women who share a terrible past. Anita Mui plays the mild-mannered wife of a police inspector who's also the mask-wearing, sword-slinging and knife-throwing crime fighter, Wonder Woman. Maggie Cheung plays the shotgun-toting, hard-boiled bounty hunter, Thief Catcher. Michelle Yeoh is Invisible Woman, the troubled but determined strong right arm of the Evil Master.

The [TV Tropes entry](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/HeroicTrio) mentions more matching details such as how Evil Master puppets Invisible Woman and that the Evil Master is reduced to bones in the final fight.

### Trailer

Found by searching for `hong kong film three women skeleton`

Comment: Thanks I will watch and check if it is true later but from the trailer it seems like what I remember. Also not sure how but search like you did give me `Kong: Skull island`

Comment: It's the "Kong" and "Skeleton" bits. It took three pages of results before I saw the actual match.

Comment: It's funny, I was almost tempted to ask an ID question lately about this one. Turns out I found it by searching something like "chinese movie with 3 woman and a skeleton" on Google.